# Updating object in react js in a function based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this imaginary case where I have a function that has a form, which I can update my data. It is a real estate agency and wants to have option to update its properties when the sellers makes some changes. Note that data might not make much sense irl but it is just for learning purpose.

A property object looks like this:

```json
  {
    owner: "John doe",
    other: {
      rooms: 3,
      windows: 6
    }
    address: {
      street: "jane doe",
      houseNr: 24
    }
  }
```

And my component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getProperty } from '../../actions'

const Property = ({ getProperty, property }) => {
  const [propertyObj, setPropertyObj] = useState(property);

  const { propertyId, owner, address, other } = propertyObj
  const propertyAddress = `${address.street},  ${address.houseNr}`  // jane doe, 24
  const { rooms } = other;

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // todo: submit the updated property
  }
  return (
    <div className='row align-items-start'>
      <div className='col col-md-6'>
        <p>Id: {propertyId}</p>
        <form>
          <div className='row'>
            <label className='mt-3'>Owner</label><input className='ml-3' type='text' name='owner' onChange={e => setPropertyObj({ owner: e.target.value })} defaultValue={owner} />
          </div>
          <div className='row'>
            <label className='mt-3 mx-3'>Rooms</label><input className='ml-3' type='text' name='rooms' onChange={e => setPropertyObj({ rooms: e.target.value })} defaultValue={rooms} />
          <div className='row'>
            <label className='mt-3 mx-3'>Property Address</label><input className='ml-3' type='text' name='propertyAddress' onChange={e => setPropertyObj({ propertyAddress: e.target.value })} defaultValue={propertyAddress} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <button onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} className='btn btn-success'>Update Property</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = reduxStoreState => {
  return {
    property: reduxStoreState.property,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProperty })(Property)
```

When attempting to update rooms property, I get:

```
TypeError: other is undefined
```

But I beliver I would get a similar error when I would try to update the property address.
I know that for property address, I have to split into street and house number to update each separately. The question is how can I update the state variable `property` so that I can submit that to my function `updatePropertyById(id, updatedProperty)`, I have seen ways to do in cases when it is a class object, but I want to use the new features of react.
How can I update the rooms for instance, without needing to also type the windows, I think the spread operator would be helpful but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updating a json object via spread operator

To use the spread operator, you have to know the *level* of the key. Lets assume we have an object:

`const obj = {"field1": {"field2": 1, "field3": 2}, "field4":3}`

To update `field3` you have to do:

`obj = {...obj, field1: {...field1, field3: newValue}}`

### In your case

This is a little different in your case, since you want to give the `key` and update the object. One way of doing this is traversing the object

```
const updateProperty = (obj, key, newVal) => {
  let tempObj = {...obj}
  Object.keys(tempObj).forEach(k => {
    if(k===key) tempObj[k] = newVal
  })
  setPropertyObj(tempObj)
}
```

Comment: what about the nested objects? Like field3, which is a property of field1?

Comment: You have to recursively iterate through the object I am afraid. Honestly, I would just do seperate functions, if your data is not dynamically growing. You know the level of each field. `updateRooms(val)` will do `{...obj, other: {...other: rooms: val}}` and other fields will have their own function. Much easier in my opinion. If you can't know the field levels, you have to iterate unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you've written:

```
...
onChange={e => setPropertyObj({ rooms: e.target.value })}
...
```

This overrides the previous value of propertyObj. What you need to do is to keep the previous state using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
onChange={e => setPropertyObj(state => ({ ...state, rooms: e.target.value })}
```

Or even better, you can write a function for this:

```
function handleChange(e) {
  setPropertyObj(state => ({
    ...state, 
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}

...
<input className='ml-3' type='text' name='rooms' onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={rooms} />
...
```

**UPDATE:** I think by `other`, you meant to use the rest syntax in object destructring.
The code `{ other } = propertyObj` means that you're looking for a property with key `other` inside `propertyObj`. If you want to assign the remaining properties to a newly defined variable, you should prepend it with three dots:

```js
const { propertyId, owner, address, ...other } = propertyObj
```

Comment: `onChange={e => setPropertyObj(state => ({ ...state, rooms: e.target.value })}` this will just add another `rooms` key at the top level. It won't change the `rooms` value inside the "other" field

Comment: @SinanYaman I updated the code. What I realized by reading his code, was that his problem isn't with the level, but with the spread operator itself.